# Pandas - Get count of rows where all values are null except for a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows (sample below for reference, original has many more columns):

[image: sample table for dataframe]

I am trying to get a list of rows where all columns are null (NaN) except for some specific columns. For example, if those specific columns are col2 and col3, I would get the first and third rows. If the specific columns are just col1, I would get only the last row.

Having just a count of the rows that meet those criteria would work too.

I know how to do this by going through each row and comparing, but is there a quicker way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
# specific columns
cols = ['col1','col2']

df[df.drop(cols, axis=1).isna().all(1)]
```

That would not check if you have data in `cols`. If you require that, you can do:

```
other_nan = df.drop(cols, axis=1).isna().all(1)
chosen_notna = df[cols].notna().any(1)

df[other_nan & chosen_notna]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for doing so.  I used `difference` to find get the dataframe excluding the specified columns, then use `isna()` and `all()` to find the empty rows:

```
def null_rows(df, exclude=None):
    exclude = [] if exclude is None else exclude
    return df[df[df.columns.difference(exclude)].isna().all(1)]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [None, 3, None, 8],
                   'col2': [1, None, 6, None],
                   'col3': [2, 4, 7, None],
                   'col4': [None, None, None, None],
                   'col5': [None, 5, None, None]})

print(null_rows(df, ['col2', 'col3']))
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   NaN   1.0   2.0  None   NaN
2   NaN   6.0   7.0  None   NaN
```